# Python list in list formatting the output

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list in list as follows:

```
bounding_time = [['58'], ['68']]
v = [['-0.00162439495203'], ['-0.000178892778126'],]
```

and `58` in `bounding_time` correspond to first item in `v` and subsequently for `68`. I trying to write to a file in such a way that I should get

```
58    -0.00162439495203
68    -0.000178892778126
```

However, with my code, which is:

```
for bt_new in bounding_time:
    bt = ''.join(map(str, bt_new))
    print bt
for v_new in v[0]:
    print v_new
```

I am getting

```
58
68
['-0.00162439495203']['-0.000178892778126']
```

Is there a way to format these lists to the desired output?

Comment: Could you review my answer, please, and please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set up the data:

```
>>> bounding_time = [['58'], ['68']]
>>> v = [['-0.00162439495203'], ['-0.000178892778126'],]
```

Now, use zip to iterate over each sublist in each list, accessing the first item in each, and concatenating those strings with 4 empty spaces:

```
>>> for i, j in zip(bounding_time, v):
...     print i[0] + '    ' + j[0]
... 
58    -0.00162439495203
68    -0.000178892778126
```

Or you can ensure you have the same width for the first column with `str.ljust`.

```
>>> for i, j in zip(bounding_time, v):
...         print i[0].ljust(6) + j[0]
... 
58    -0.00162439495203
68    -0.000178892778126
```

Comment: @Deepak, thanks, and note that you now have enough reputation (15) that you can upvote answers that you find helpful.